# jQuery Show Modal on Form Submit and do different actions depending on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a form that I want to submit. On submit, I preventDefault and perform an ajax request that essentially checks for an existing record:

1. If no record exists, should continue as normal
2. If record exists, then shows a modal asking if the user would like to close out the existing record.
   i) If they accept, just sets a value to an id field
   ii) If they deny, just continues

Way I have it currently, just goes into an infinite loop. I could set a global boolean variable and use that to then check in the form submission to know if it should just continue, but surely there is a more elegant way to accomplish what I am after?

Javascript (Some laravel template code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#button-close-previous-status', function() {
            $('#form-create-status').submit();
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#button-ignore-previous-status', function() {
            $('#open_status_id').val('');
            $('#form-create-status').submit();
        });

        $('#modal-title-close-previous-status').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#close-status-end-date').empty();
            $('#close-status-status').empty();
            $('#close-status-start-date').empty();
            $('#open_status_id').val('');
        });

        $('#form-create-status').submit(function(e) {
            // this code prevents form from actually being submitted
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;

            if (!$('#status_start').val()) {
                swtAlert('error', '{{__('Missing Information')}}', '{{__('Please enter the status start date')}}');
            }
            else {
                var $form = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('baadmin.students.bursaries.statuses.get_open_student_bursary_statuses',['student'=>$student->id,'bursary'=>$student_bursary->id])}}",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    context: $form,
                    data: {
                        status_start: $('#status_start').val()
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.id>0) {
                            var parts =$('#status_start').val().split('-');
                            var end_date = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
                            end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() - 1);
                            end_date = end_date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'});

                            $('#close-status-end-date').text(end_date);
                            $('#close-status-status').text(data.text);
                            $('#close-status-start-date').text(data.status_start);
                            $('#open_status_id').val(data.id);

                            $('#modal-close-previous-status').modal('show');
                        }
                        else {
                            swtAlert('error','Communications Error',"Couldn't fetch existing statuses. Cant request auto-close.");
                            // make sure that you are no longer handling the submit event; clear handler
                            this.off('submit');
                            // actually submit the form
                            this.submit();
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Modal HTML (Excluding form HTML for length purposes, but just assume there is a form named/id of "form-create-status", includes some laravel template code):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-close-previous-status" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title-close-previous-status" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-close-previous-status">{{__('Close Previous Status')}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>We found a previously open status. Would you like to close that status with a status end date of <span id="close-status-end-date"></span>.</p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Found  Status:</strong><br>
                    Status: <span id="close-status-status"></span><br/>
                    Status Start: <span id="close-status-start-date"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{ Form::button(__('Dont Change Anything'), ['type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-secondary', 'data-dismiss'=>'modal','id'=>'button-ignore-previous-status']) }}
                {{ Form::button(__('Close Previous Status'), ['type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-success','id'=>'button-close-previous-status']) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```